# SAML parsing in JAVA

Tags: java, android, attributes, saml

How can i parse the values i got from SAML response?
I want to get the AttributeValue of a specific AttributeName.

Something like this.

```
<saml:Attribute AttributeName="FirstName" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims">
<saml:AttributeValue>MY FirstName</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the java applications are using [opensaml library](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual) to parse the SAML request and response. Once you unmarshall it using opensaml,  you can travels to attribute statement and extract the value. Also there are some [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681083/consume-samlresponse-token) that may be helpful for you.