# I am using ADFS SAML, how to redirect request to Application URL

Tags: java, saml-2.0, adfs

we need to configure ADFS in our application, we are using oiosaml to get the idp token and we successfully getting the token from idp. How we will use this token?, so it will redirect us into the application without asking the login again. currently it redirecting us to application login page.

URl we are redirecting after adfs/ls:
https://localhost/xxx/saml/SAMLAssertionConsumer.
which is asking for application login again. but it should not be.

we need expertise here, thanks in advance.
New in ADFS please ask your queries, if above is not clear.

Comment: Did you implement the code to read the SAML Assertion and sign in the user to your application?

Comment: no, please guide me further i am using java. so i have to modify SMALAssertionConsumer.java or i have to write a new class which while read the SMAL Assertion and sign in the user.

Comment: You can use `OpenSAML` Java library to read the SAML Response. Here is a very basic example of how to use OpenSAML library: http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-read-saml-20-response-with.html. Before that, I recommend you to read more about SAML - implementation details. Here is another Stackoverflow article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681083/consume-samlresponse-token

Comment: thank you nikhil,  if there are any session or cookies are available my application redirect the user into the application without asking login page.. so similarly if i pass the cookies session id with requested url it will redirect us into the application?

Comment: How can you pass cookies or session ID if the user is not logged into your application? And if it logged in then there is no need for anything? And even if you can, how can you verify the authenticity of the source?